# Решение ОДУ на Python

Tags: python

уважаемые форумчане! Есть одна проблема, написал скрипт для решения задачи Коши, методом Эйлера, чтобы можно было строить графики ошибок и вычислять ошибку численного решения, однако, не могу понять, почему возникла такая ошибка:

```py
# Author: Alm99-collab
# Date: 25/11/2021 2:00
# Description: MSUT STANKIN Μyagkov Alexandr IDM - 21 - 03

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


# фнукция решатель методом Эйлера (прямая схема)
def euler(func, Y0, b, n):
    """Решение ОДУ u'=f(y,x), начальное условие y(0) = U0 , c n шагами, пока  x = b - конец отрезка интегрирования."""
    x = np.zeros(n + 1)
    y = np.zeros(n + 1)
    y[0] = Y0
    x[0] = 0
    dx = b / float(n)
    for k in range(n):
        x[k + 1] = x[k] + dx
        y[k + 1] = y[k] + dx * func(y[k], x[k])
    return y, x


# Сравнение точного аналитического решения и численного

# функция возврата точного решения
def y_exact(x):
    return ((x ** 2) / 2) - (x / 2) + 0.75 * math.exp(-2 * x) + 0.25


# Функция постановки задачи: y'= y
def func(y, x):
    return x ** 2 - 2 * y


y, x = euler(func, Y0 = y_exact(0), b = 1, n = 10)
y_e = y_exact(y)


err = np.abs(y_e - y).max()
# err = np.abs(y_e - y).max()

# построение графика
plt.plot(x, y, 'r-', label = 'numerical')
plt.plot(x, y_exact, 'b-',label = 'exact', marker = '*', markersize = 3)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.legend()
plt.title = "Решение для ОДУ y'= y, y(0)=1"
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('Sols.png', dpi=600)
plt.show()

Ошибка следующая возникла:

      File "C:\SM2-rep\euler_ode.py", line 33, in func return x ** 2 - 2 * y_exact(x)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable


Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема, так то все вроде бы нормально,но...
```

Comment: вызов func(y[k], x[k]) и определение функции
def func(y_exact, x)
Ты передаешь в функцию элементы, и пытаешься один из элементов использовать как функцию, вообще неясно к чему ты вообще сами функции передаёшь в функции.

Comment: я определил таким образом функции, чтобы можно было рассчитать погрешность, просто, получается, что в func надо записать другой результат, как то иначе ее определить, дабы она возвращала правильный результат...

Comment: что должна принимать func у вас? два числа?

Comment: должна возвращать выражение, dx/dy, т.е. правую часть ОДУ, где y(x) уже есть известное аналитическое решение, а принимать y,x

Comment: ну так уберите там y_exact как имя аргумента - назовите аргумент просто y и вызывайте y_exact(y)

Comment: так у меня функция точного решения зависит от x